# Equal Columns in PHP

Tags: php

I have an array and I'm getting the results as list elements. -- What I'm trying to do though is to count the total number of items and have it split so that one list would appear on the left (via CSS of course) and the other half on the right.

My code thus far is below...

```
<?php 
$terms = get_field('featured_cities');
foreach ($terms as $term) {
  echo '<li><a href="'.get_term_link($term->slug, 'cities').'">'.$term->name.'</a></li>';
}
?>
```

Is it possible someone could point me in the direction of getting this done?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`$terms` contains your total set of elements. It is a simple matter to split the stack evenly and then print both lists.

Here is a good way to do it:

```
 $list = []; $list2 = [];
 foreach ($terms as $k => $term) {
    if ( ($k % 2) == 0) $list[] = $term;
    else $list2[] = $term;
 }
 // You now have two lists, $list and $list2.
```

If you would prefer to do it in just one loop, consider setting `float: left; width: 50%` to the style of your `li` elements, but if you go down this route, you will need an element with `clear: both` at the end to prevent nasty style surprises.

Answer (score 1):

You could use a [multi-column layout](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/CSS/Using_multi-column_layouts) to separate both columns